# bBox of SVG is zero

Tags: d3.js, svg

Why the result of `bBox.width`, `bBox.height` are both 0? I expect them to be both 500px, how to rectify it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.8/d3.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.9/d3.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script-->
<style>
    rect {
        stroke: #9A8B7A;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: #CF7D1C;

    }

    svg{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background:blue;
    }
</style>
<body>


</body>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
    var bBox = svg.node().getBBox();
    console.log(bBox.width + 'x' + bBox.height);






</script>
```

Comment: Put an element (a rect, a circle, a line etc, it doesn't matter) inside that SVG and you'll see something very interesting...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks, but nothing change actually, the `getBoundingClientRect` works

Comment: It does change, easy to prove: https://jsfiddle.net/tgj6gzcz/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks! But say if I put `svg.append("rect").attr("width",100).attr("height",100);`, it shows 100 x100, rather than 500 x 500.

Comment: I never said it will show the SVG size. I said *"something very interesting"* will happen. Based on this, you can start to think about how `getBBox` works...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have a further question here from our previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691580/resize-the-svgs-according-to-windows-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `getBoundingClientRect` instead of `getBBox`.